# Why is 在 translated as "during" in this sentence rather then "at"?

Tags: grammar, terminology

This sentence

中国人喜欢在端午节吃粽子。

is translated as,

Chinese People like to eat Zongzi during the Dragon Boat Festival.

Why is 在 translated as "during" rather then "at".

Answer (score 2):

Don't use 'at the Dragon Boat Festival', that suggests to me a festival in a specific geographical location or place.

You could say 'at 5 o'clock' or 'at midnight', because those are specific times. 'At Christmas time' designates a specific time in the year.

在端午节这天，人们都喜欢吃粽子。
During the Dragon Boat Festival, everybody likes munching Zongzi.

or

On the day of the Dragon Boat Festival, everybody likes munching Zongzi.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no specification,  "在端午节" can mean 1. "在端午节**期間**" (during the Dragon Boat Festival **period**) or 2. "在端午节**當日**" (on **the day** of the Dragon Boat Festival)

Just like in English, "I will come home during Christmas time' and "I will come home on Christmas day' are different

Comment: Try 'on Christmas day, on the day of' sounds much better!